# How does docker know the digest for each blob when pulling from registry?

Tags: docker

## OCI spec

From the [spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md#pull) you can:

- Pull manifests using the endpoint `/v2/<name>/manifests/<reference>`
- Pull blobs using the endpoint `/v2/<name>/blobs/<digest>`

## Proof of Concept

Used a reverse proxy to catch the HTTP requests made by the docker client when pulling a docker image from the registry, here is the output:

1. Get a valid token and make a HEAD request to verify that the manifest exists.
   [image: Checking manifest]

> Notice how we get back the image Id on `Docker-Content-Digest` header, as specified in the standard.

2. After validating that the manifest exists just requests a token for each of the layers and it's data:
   [image: First layer]

## Question

Where in between step 1 and 2 docker knows the digest for each layer just by making a `HEAD` request to the manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Docker applies caching and it doesn't get removed using the command `docker rm <image>`. Here is the output of a non cached image:
[image: Docker pull]

It follows the steps:

1. `HEAD` to check if there is such manifest
2. Gets the manifest
3. Gets the manifest for my platform (amd64)
4. Gets the first layer